# Google URL shortener android API always throws exception

Tags: android

Here is my code for my method:

```
Urlshortener.Builder builder = new Urlshortener.Builder (AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), AndroidJsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), null);
    Urlshortener urlshortener = builder.build();

    Url url = new Url();

    url.setLongUrl(longUrl);
    try
    {
        url = urlshortener.url().insert(url).execute();
        return url.getId();
    } catch (IOException e)
    {            
        return null;
    }
```

I'm fairly certain that I'm using the API incorrectly, however, I can't figure out where I'm going wrong.  Does anyone know the correct way or have a link to a simple tutorial?

Here is what IOException e contains:

```
Unexpected response code for CONNECT: 403
```

I think I need to add my API key somewhere but I can't seem to figure out where.

Comment: What exception do you get? :) It'd be great if you could post your logcat

Comment: Appears to be an authentication issue.

Comment: `403` is `Forbidden`.

Comment: Yes it is, hence my 'Appears to be an authentication issue' comment.

Comment: did you try appending key=yourApiKey to the end of the request url? That's what the site says. https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, but when using 4G (mobile network) it throws that 403 error.  When connected to WIFI, it works perfect.